# photo gallery navigation - css overlay

Tags: css

I'm creating simple photo gallery (php) for a responsive site and when a photo is displayed I want to have overlay with navigation displayed on mouse hover (for desktop, taking another approach for mobile). The overlay (over photo) is supposed to be div of same width as the given photo (variable width), left navigation is 25% of left part and right one 25% on the right. When photo is displayed and mouse cursor is outside of photo nothing is visible. When mouse cursor hovers over left part big < is displayed. And > for right side. < and > should be vertically centered.
I got it working but only with absolute positioning, declaring exact position but the result is not responsive and breaks when windows is smaller:

```
jsfiddle.net/mwf5618r/
```

I tried using flex and z-index too but did not get it to work. Below is what I created with flex but does not work. I don't need to use flex as long as it is responsive.

```
jsfiddle.net/x1jexvb0/
```

Will you help me to make it cleanly and responsive? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some HTML elements included the CSS, hopefully this will done the work for you. Check also the new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwf5618r/1/embed/

HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative;">

    <a href="#left" class="photo_nav left">
        <div id="photo_nav">
            &lt;
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#right" class="photo_nav right">
        <div id="photo_nav">
            &gt;
        </div>
    </a>
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;margin:auto;">
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_w0r3cYUSD7A/Sob415afOVI/AAAAAAAABa4/-J_vkiTkITE/s1600/sunflare.jpgg" class="photo" style="width:100%;">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.photo_nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity:0;
    font-size: 200px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
a.photo_nav:hover {
    color:#fff;
    opacity:0.6;
}
a.photo_nav #photo_nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
a.photo_nav.left {left: 0;}
a.photo_nav.right {right: 0;}
a.photo_nav.left div#photo_nav {left: 0;}
a.photo_nav.right div#photo_nav {right: 0;}
```

Well maybe this?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the navigation divs 100% of the height of the image so the whole 25% on left/right is hoverable for navigation. And navigation divs should start with the edge of the image. I'll keep trying..

Comment: Check out the new update, Did some changes in the CSS, hopefully this could help you. The navigation div starts at the top of the edge, The div inside the A tag is positioned at the verticle middle/center.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for your help! :-)

Comment: Thanks to that, please make sure you vote my answer and mark is as the solution :)